# Cant perform click on Android API V22

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I update my android project from API 21 to API 22, but I can't perform any click at all. This is the error that logcat give me

```
 05-27 12:09:41.881  29097-29485/com.app.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.app.app, PID: 29097
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onLogin(View) in the activity class android.support.v7.internal.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'login_button'
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3828)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18482)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onLogin [class android.view.View]
            at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
            at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3821)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18482)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My buttons works perfectly before updating to api v22

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.app.AccountActivity"
    android:background="@color/main">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/account_register"
            android:id="@+id/register_button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF4F8FFF"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:onClick="onRegister"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/account_login"
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FF2055A9"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:onClick="onLogin"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Connect with Twitter"
        android:id="@+id/twitter_button"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:background="#FF1C1347"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/account_facebook"
        android:id="@+id/facebook_button"
        android:layout_above="@+id/twitter_button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:background="#FF32246E"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:onClick="onFacebookLogin" />

    <view
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        class="com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton"
        android:id="@+id/facebook_auth"
        android:layout_above="@+id/facebook_button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/support"
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_above="@+id/facebook_button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/support_message"
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
        android:background="#FF32246E"
        android:id="@+id/login_in_view"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center">

        <view
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            class="com.github.rahatarmanahmed.cpv.CircularProgressView"
            android:id="@+id/view3"
            app:cpv_indeterminate="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView20">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:src="@drawable/landing_2x"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_landing"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

On the Activity I have

```
       package com.app.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AccessToken;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.GraphRequest;
import com.facebook.GraphResponse;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;
import com.app.app.support.AppJsonRequest;
import com.app.app.support.AppNetwork;
import com.app.app.support.AppSession;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class AccountActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static final int REGISTER_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public static final int LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE = 2;

    private LoginButton fb_login = null;
    private Button login;
    private Button register;
    private CallbackManager manager = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);
        fb_login = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_auth);
        fb_login.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("user_hometown", "user_location", "user_status", "public_profile", "user_photos", "email", "user_friends"));
        manager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        fb_login.registerCallback(manager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                Log.i("App", "Login FB success");
                onFacebookLogin();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                String msg = getString(R.string.fb_login_cancelled);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                enableButtons();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(AccountActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                enableButtons();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_account, menu);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Tracker tracker = ((AppApp) getApplication()).getTracker();
        tracker.setScreenName("Account");
        tracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
    }

    public void disableButtons() {
        login.setEnabled(false);
        register.setEnabled(false);
        //facebook.setEnabled(false);
        findViewById(R.id.login_in_view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void enableButtons() {
        login.setEnabled(true);
        register.setEnabled(true);
        //facebook.setEnabled(true);
        findViewById(R.id.login_in_view).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    public void onFacebookLogin(View view) {
        if (AppApp.DEBUG) Log.i("App", "Facebook login");
        disableButtons();
        fb_login.performClick();
    }

    private void onFacebookLogin() {
        AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        if (accessToken != null) {
            GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                    onFacebookUser(object);
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }
    }

    private void onFacebookUser(JSONObject user) {
        AppSession.onFacebookLogin(this, user.optString("id", "0"), user.optString("email", "username@domain.com"));
        AppJsonRequest request = AppNetwork.newAppRequest("register.php");
        request.addParam("name", user.optString("first_name", "Name"));
        request.addParam("last", user.optString("last_name", "Last"));
        request.addParam("email", user.optString("email", "username@domain.com"));
        request.addParam("sex", user.optString("gender", "undefined"));
        request.addParam("fb", user.optString("id", "0"));
        request.setListener(new AppJsonRequest.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(JSONObject result) {
                int id = result.optInt("user", 0);
                if (id != 0) {
                    AppSession.onLogin(AccountActivity.this, id);
                    // we will call this from main
                    //updateFacebook();
                    getFacebookFriends();
                    goToMain();
                } else if (AppApp.DEBUG) {
                    Log.e("App", "register.php error " + result.toString());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(AppJsonRequest.ERROR error) {
                if (AppApp.DEBUG) Log.e("App", "AppJsonRequest error " + error);
            }
        });
        request.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        manager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REGISTER_REQUEST_CODE:
        case LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                goToMain();
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    private void goToMain() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, OnBoardingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    public void updateFacebook() {
        AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(token, "/me/home", new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                JSONObject response = graphResponse.getJSONObject();
                JSONArray array = response.optJSONArray("data");
                if (array != null) {
                    AppJsonRequest request = AppNetwork.newAppRequest("checkin.php");
                    request.addParam("data", array.toString());
                    request.addParam("from", "facebook");
                    request.addParam("user", AppSession.USER);
                    request.addParam("access_token", AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken());
                    request.execute();
                }
            }
        });
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("fields", "from,place,message,object_id,type");
        bundle.putString("limit", "100");
        bundle.putString("with", "location");
        request.setParameters(bundle);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

    public void onRegister(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REGISTER_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    public void onLogin(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, LOGIN_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    public void getFacebookFriends() {
        AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(token, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONArray jsonArray, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                AppJsonRequest request = AppNetwork.newAppRequest("friendsLocation.php");
                request.addParam("from", "facebook");
                request.addParam("data", jsonArray.toString());
                request.addParam("user", AppSession.USER);
                request.execute();
            }
        });
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("fields", "id,name,location,hometown");
        request.setParameters(bundle);
        request.executeAsync();
    }

}
```

Comment: some code would help

Comment: Make sure, you are using this: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' as a support library.

Comment: @PrankulGarg actually I'm using com.android.support:appcompact-v7:22.1.1 as dependencies libraries

Comment: Or just don't use `onClick` attribute in XML. It wouldn't work with fragments either. Google Butterknife, then you just annotate the methods you already have with `@OnClick(R.id.id_of_the_button` and call `Butterknife.inject(this)` after `setContentView(...)` and you're good to go.

Comment: This solution seems to work @EugenPechanec. I'm testing it